# Can thumb of SeekBar be tracked on x and y coordinates?

Tags: android, android-image, android-view, android-progressbar

I am doing an android app, I want to drag an image and place it on top of a SeekBar at some particular location and correspondingly when the progress of the SeekBar or the thumb collides with the image location I want to play a song, for this to happen I guess I would have to track the location of the thumb on x and y coordinates, can this be achieved? Is there some other way to go around?

Comment: Which version of sdk you develop with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should do the things in the `onThouchEvent` which has a `ACTION_MOVE` event.
2. There are some useful method you can use : `getHitRect` which can get the rect of the view so that you can use `Rect.contains(int x,int y)` to get whether the view is in the specified loacation, `getLocationOnScreen` can help you get the absolute position of the view in the screen so that all the point you get is in the same coordinate system.

Comment: The SeekBar which I employ plays a song already and user cannot drag its thumb, how do I use onTouchEvent then?

Comment: You should put the image you want drag in a view, then put the view and the seekbar in your custom layout so that you can override the `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: I am already able to drag views using onTouch, I want to detect the collision of the view with the thumb of SeekBar

Comment: Get the rect of your seekbar when user start dragging your image, then in the `onTouchEvent` you can get the pointer of the image on the ACTION_MOVE case continuously, Then judge whether the pointer of the image is contained in the rect of the seekbar.

Comment: I have also done that, I place the image in the boundaries of SeekBar, the thumb of seekbar moves along in tune with the song played, I have no control over it, now if I place the view say at 100dp on x axis in the seekbar, how do I know the coordinates of the thumb when it is at 100dip away from seekbar from the starting position?

Comment: Basically I want to track the position of progress of the seekBar on x and y axis

Comment: English is not my tongue language, I'm confused, From the question you asked, you put a specified view on the seekbar by dragging and the song is playing so that the progress is increasing, you want to know whether the progress collides with the specified view ?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to know when progress collides with the view that is placed on that seekBar.

Comment: I know, You can get the progress when the song is playing and the width of the seekbar so that you can convert the progress to px that in the seekbar coordinate i think, then convert the seekbar coordinate to screen coordinate.that you can judge whether collides happened. I think this maybe works.